# Does tensoring by a reflexive sheaf induce isomorphism between Ext groups?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety which has only terminal singularities. 
Let $\Omega^1_X$ be the Kahler differential sheaf on $X$ and $\omega_X$ be the dualizing sheaf on $X$. For a coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, let $F^{* *}$ be its double dual.

**Question** Are ${\rm Ext}^2 ((\Omega^1_X)^{* *}, \mathcal{O}_X)$ 
and 
${\rm Ext}^2 ((\Omega^1_X)^{* *} \otimes \omega_X, \omega_X) $ isomorphic?

If $X$ is Gorenstein, they are isomorphic. I want to know the situation when $X$ is non-Gorenstein.

Comment: I don't know any example, but I should strongly suspect that the answer is no, they are not isomorphic.  Is there a reason you expect that they might be isomorphic?  The $\text{Hom} = \text{Ext}^0$ is certainly an isomorphism.  Is there a particular terminal singularity you have in mind?  You should be able to check this question explicitly in Macaulay2.

Comment: In fact, I want a counterexample, particularly when $X$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-Fano 3-fold. 